# Read from database in isolation if a service is running in cluster mode

Tags: java, database, mongodb, scheduled-tasks

I am working on a scheduler. I use spring schedule to run the job every 2 mins interval. I scan a database for pending tasks and execute them.

This works fine if I have only one instance of my service. I have to deploy multiple instances of the service.

I run into the situation where two instances are running the same job as every instance read the same job from db. And it gets executed twice.

I am using mongodb to maintain the jobs and their status.
How can I ensure that all the instances execute the different job?

Comment: Update the job to a status that it's already being handled?

Comment: If both the services read the same records at the same time.

Comment: Then one of them can't update the record because the other one already updated it?

Comment: Updating is not a concern. Both services read the tasks togather and start execution. Then it is a problem

Comment: Update is not the concern, it's the solution. Since you can have only one value in the database, use it either to mark that the job is already taken (=second one can't update it anymore) or update the handler id there. Or something other similar that will let you know which one is suppose to handle the job.